# Get fb page scoped user id for messenger app

Tags: facebook, fbsdk

I recently discovered a facebook marketing app that sends message (on messenger) after the user leaves a comment on a particular post from a page (as an autoresponder), given that the user does not interact with messenger application (For never and not logging using facebook at this app).

Using Webhook events, I can get the user ID that post the comment, but this ID is different from page scoped ID (PSID) used to send the message.

Does anyone have any idea or a trick to do this?

Comment: No there is no way to get a page scoped user ID from an app scoped user ID.

Comment: Ok .. But .. how can work this application?

Comment: You can't. Bots can only respond to messages the users sends it.

Answer (score 0):

Let check if the id you get on the webhook is `app-scoped id`, you can you this method to get the `page-scoped id`: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching/

Comment: I get following when I try ID matching. 

 `(#100) Invalid token. Can only query using page access tokens where the page is owned by the same business as the app`

Documentation does say that both page and app should belong to same business, But how can I get PSID if  user logged in my website and I have the user token, page token and user page does not belong to my businness?

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Feed Webhook event](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks/reference/page/#feed) to get `comment_id`, 
Use `comment_id` to send message through [private_replies](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.12/object/private_replies).